# Statsmodels heteroskedasticity test: consider weight of data next to difference in variance

Tags: python, statsmodels

For a current project, I have generated a number of data points that show a clear triangular pattern:

[image]

When trying to quantify this pattern through a Statsmodels Breusch-Pagan test, the data however fails to show a heteroskedasticity (i.e. a change in the y-axis variances driven by an independent x-axis variable) at a significance level.

I assume this to be the case as the test only checks for a difference in variances but fails to consider the much higher data density at the right end of the scatter plot.

Hence my question: is there any other heteroskedasticity based on Statsmodels that draws stronger attention to the weight of the data, not only the difference in variances?

Comment: That data looks pretty homoskedastic.  The main issue you face is that most of the data points fall within the 25- 40 range, and so the test will naturally place more weight on these observations. The observations in the 15-25 range may have a smaller variance. However, since there is only a small number, they do not make a large contribution to the test statistics's value.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - this is what I thought. I tried to apply a Goldfeld-Quandt test for this purpose that divides the data field into two halves (i.e. 15 - 26 and 27 - 38), which however did not show any heteroskedasticity at a relevance level either...

Comment: You won't see it there either, because each half is pretty homoskedastic. You may see it if you "thin" the data with x > 30 so that your data is more balanced in terms of their x values.  Of course, it isn't clear why one would want to do this and it may be the case that your data is simply homoskedastic. Have you tried `het_white`?

Comment: I get your point here. I have run the White-Test with the following results `{'LM Statistic': 1.1371990222405213, 'LM-Test p-value': 0.5663180056487019, 'F-Statistic': 0.563352443705467, 'F-Test p-value': 0.5701980351595539}`. No significant heteroskedasticity detected through this test...

Comment: Sounds like your data is not statistically different from homoskedastic data, at least as far as regression standard errors are concerned.

Comment: Yes it seems like it. Thanks anyways for your views/thoughts